# Pattern to break up external API calls?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to wrap my mind around how I would go about implementing this specific problem. We have an external API that performs some logic and returns back the result of that logic. Unfortunately, the API returns a new object as the result as opposed to just the part that I am interested in. For example, the code would look something like this:

```
public class ComplexObject {
    //lots of fields
}

public interface LogicApplier {
    LogicResult applyLogic(ComplexObject obj);
}

public class LogicResult {
    ComplexObject result;

    public ComplexObject getResult();
}

public class FirstImplementation {

    private LogicApplier _applier;

    public Implementation(LogicApplier applier) {
        _applier = applier;
    }

    public ComplexObject mainImplementation (ComplexObject apply) {
        LogicResult logicResult = _applier.applyLogic(apply);

        ComplexObject newComplexObject = logicResult.getResult();

        //Do some other stuff with new ComplexObject
    }
}
```

So question is: what would be the best way to put a limit on LogicApplier's "power" over FirstImplementation? For example, our motivation to call logic in the first place is to derive a missing field, let's say "name". This field could potentially be different in, say, SecondImplementation where that implementation is now looking to derive "street address" from LogicApplier API. However, there is nothing to stop LogicApplier from changing some other field, say "idNumber".

Is this best solved by a adding an interface for our specific implementations and manually mapping fields? Something like:

```
public interface SecondImplementationLogicApplier {

    public String deriveAddress(ComplexObject o);
}

public class LimitedImplementationLogicApplier implements FirstImplementationLogicApplier, SecondImplementationLogicApplier {
    LogicApplier _applier;
    public LimitedImplementationLogicApplier(LogicApplier applier) {
        _applier = applier;
    }

    public String deriveFirstName(ComplexObject o) {
     LogicResult res = _applier.applyLogic(o);
     return res.firstName;
    }


    public String deriveFirstName(ComplexObject o) {
     LogicResult res = _applier.applyLogic(o);
     return res.address;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on right track with your `LimitedImplementationLogicApplier`. You should guard objects in your domain from possible corruption from the outside. Only update fields that you need.

It looks like your `ComplexObject` is mutable. I'd consider hiding it behind the immutable interface (that don't have any setters or way to change the object exposed) and pass immutable interface into your `LimitedImplementationLogicApplier` so its got no chance of mutating `ComplexObject`.

If your API requires `ComplexObject` type and you can't change that, to prevent mutation you could:

Option 1

Create a `clone` of your base `ComplexObject` instance and pass it into the API. After you've got the result back, you update the needed fields on untouched `base` instance. This will work nicely if `ComplexObject` is "thing in itself" and changes in its state does not have side effects outside of the class instance, like changing databases or affecting other state.

If mutation of `ComplexObject` has side effects or `may have them in future` then its a real trouble.

Option 2

Inherit a `ReadonlyComplexObject` class from `ComplexObject` and pass that into the API. In `ReadonlyComplexObject` you will suppress all the behavior of the parent to prevent modification.

This is hacky in my opinion and will create more work later - if `ComplexObject` will be extended with new properties later you will need to make changes to `ReadonlyComplexObject` otherwise mutation will still occur.

Comment: `ComplexObject` is a mutable generated class that is used throughout our code base, which complicates things.

So is your suggestion to have `LimitedImplementationLogicApplier` take in a wrapper, like `ComplexObjectWrapperForImplementationOne` (better name pending), which wraps our `ComplexObject` into something that only exposes setters for fields that we are expecting mutation for?

Comment: I'd prefer an interface over `ComplexObject` (can you generate it with that interface?), but if its not possible, the wrapper will also work. If you can pass something immutable into your "deriving" logic, you will be sure your objects stay unmodified.

Comment: Unfortunately, it cannot be generated with an interface. Also, the "deriving" logic should be treated here as an external API, so we do not have control over the implementation. It requires a `ComplexObject` and returns a `ComplexObject`, which is scary. So I suppose the best way forward would be a wrapper around `ComplexObject` to only expose some designated fields, and a wrapper around `LogicApplier ` to use this new `ComplexObject` wrapper. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Updated the answer. I think my `option 2` is closest to your wrapper idea. I think you won't be able to have a wrapper of type `ComplexObject` (thats what your external API  wants right?) with `less` fields / methods than the `ComplexObject` type itself

Comment: I think I'm leaning more toward Option 1 for the time being, thanks for the brainstorming. Reasoning being: Option 2 would require building a new wrapper class to truly have control over the fields... which isn't a bad idea, but probably a problem for a different day. Seems like cloning the object, mapping that to a specified return type (`ImplOneResultObject` or something like that), and hiding that all within a wrapper around `LogicApplier`. The API for `LogicApplier` calls changes very little for client, and hides need to clone/cast/etc. Thanks again for help.